# String to Multi-Dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, regex, multidimensional-array

Imagine that I have a variable that contains following value:

```
$content = "[['a', 'b', 1, 4], ['a2', 'b2', 12, 42], ['a3', 'b3', 13, 43], ['a4', 'b4', 14, 44]]";
```

I want to parse this string and create actual multi-dimensional array in PHP.
For example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'a'
            [1] => 'b'
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'a2'
            [1] => 'b2'
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 42
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'a3'
            [1] => 'b3'
            [2] => 13
            [3] => 43
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'a4'
            [1] => 'b4'
            [2] => 14
            [3] => 44
        )
)
```

For that purpose, first of all I tried to parse that string via regular expression:

```
$pattern = "/\[(\[.+\])\]/i";
```

However I failed when I tried it as following:

```
$pattern = "/\[(\[.+\])\]/i";
$content = "[['a', 'b', 1, 4], ['a2', 'b2', 12, 42], ['a3', 'b3', 13, 43], ['a4', 'b4', 14, 44]]";

preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $results);

print_r($results);
```

And the output is:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => [['a', 'b', 1, 4], ['a2', 'b2', 12, 42], ['a3', 'b3', 13, 43], ['a4', 'b4', 14, 44]] ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => ['a', 'b', 1, 4], ['a2', 'b2', 12, 42], ['a3', 'b3', 13, 43], ['a4', 'b4', 14, 44] ) 
)
```

So;

1. How can I solve that regex issue?
2. Are there any other ways to implement that problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't json handle the curly brackets; I don't think it works for "[, ]" brackets?

Comment: Yes, just realised that

Comment: Damn, these "array" brackets are using in JSON; in JSON "array" :) Dummy mistake buddy, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to JSON, which is simple all you need to do is replace the single quotes with double quotes, then it will be a JSON String

```
$content = "[['a', 'b', 1, 4], ['a2', 'b2', 12, 42], ['a3', 'b3', 13, 43], ['a4', 'b4', 14, 44]]";
$c = str_replace("'", '"', $content);

print_r(json_decode($c));
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a2
            [1] => b2
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 42
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => a3
            [1] => b3
            [2] => 13
            [3] => 43
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => a4
            [1] => b4
            [2] => 14
            [3] => 44
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

use `json_decode` but first replace quotes to double quotes:

`json_decode(str_replace('\'','"',$content));`

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, that is a valid PHP array definition also:

```
eval("\$results = $content;");

// or

eval('$results = ' . $content . ';');
```

Then `$results` will be that array.